# How to read integers from Console in Go using Scanf?

Tags: go

So I'm trying to do a codeforces problem (my first!) and I'm trying to read the input.

I initially tried using os.Args, but that caused a runtime error.

I am now trying this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    var m int
    var a int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &m)
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &a)

    rectangleArea := n*m
    squareArea := a*a
    nSquares := 0
    for i := 0; i < rectangleArea + squareArea; i = i + squareArea {
        nSquares++
    }

    fmt.Println(nSquares)

}
```

But this seems to go into infinite loop when I run it with the arguments 6 6 4. Well, it goes into infinite loop with any argument.

What's going on?

Comment: i just tried this with 6 6 4
and it printed 4

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: Can I ask ... what sort of debugging of this have you done yourself? Have you dumped the value of `rectangleArea + squareArea` prior to the loop to see what the value is? Have you checked the step value at each iteration? Have you dumped the individual values that you're scanning via `Scanf`? What about the __errors that Scanf can return__ .. have you checked those instead of ignoring them?

Comment: The fact that it goes into an infinite loop indicates that squareArea is somehow 0.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I can't do that - I'm running this in the CodeForces environment, and it literally just tells me 'runtime error', despite working in my local environment